# Bar Chart - Histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, histogram

I want to plot a histogram of my dataset which contains two columns, one with names and the other one with values which looks like that:

```
 City      Values
 Graz       2799
 Innsbruck  2802
 Klagenfurt 2591
 Linz       3016
 Salzburg   2716
 Wien       2252
```

I want to create a bar histogram which shows how much in the value for each one of the names having the Names variable in the horizontal axis.
I've tried the following code:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=City))
```

but what I am getting back is not what I want and it looks like that:

[image: bar histogram]

Do you know how I can fix that? Or do you have any suggestions about any other plot which will show me a similar result as what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the barplot with your values.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=City, y=Values)) +
     geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

From the docs:

> By default, geom_bar uses stat="bin" . This makes the height of each
> bar equal to the number of cases in each group, and it is incompatible
> with mapping values to the y aesthetic. If you want the heights of the
> bars to represent values in the data, use stat="identity" and map a
> value to the y aesthetic.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `barplot`

```
barplot(Values ~ City, df1)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(City = c("Graz", "Innsbruck", "Klagenfurt", "Linz", 
"Salzburg", "Wien"), Values = c(2799L, 2802L, 2591L, 3016L, 2716L, 
2252L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It solved my problem.